# v-runtime-template and vuex cause infinite update loop

Tags: vuejs2, vuex

I came across an infinite loop that really confused me. I used [v-runtime-template](https://github.com/alexjoverm/v-runtime-template) to load dynamic forms, everything works fine when I use static data, but switches to an infinite loop after getting data from vuex.

I have written two examples with [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/l2k28nkxy9), but note that clicking on Demo2 may cause the browser to die.

The loading of data needs to be done through vuex. How to solve the problem of infinite loop, I look forward to your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solved this problem. defining a sub-component to load v-runtime-template, get data in the parent component and passing it to sub-components via props.
Code is like this:

```
<template>
  <form data-vv-scope="custom-form" v-if="html">
    <form-content :html="html" :data="data" :permission="permission" />
  </form>
</template>

<script>
import FormContent from "@/components/FormContent.vue";
import { mapState } from "vuex";

export default {
  name: "demo2",
  computed: mapState({
    html: state => state.html,
    data: state => state.data,
    permission: state => state.permission
  }),
  components: {
    FormContent
  },
  created() {
    this.$store.dispatch("loadForm");
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: I don't know How this answer can work perfectly! You save my life bro... T_T