# v-runtime-template vuejs cannot access root property

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-cli

This is my page.vue

```
<template>
   <div>
    <v-runtime-template :template="template"></v-runtime-template>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import VRuntimeTemplate from "v-runtime-template";
 
export default {
  data: () => ({
    template: `
      <span>{{sample}}</span>
    `
  }),
  components: {
    VRuntimeTemplate
  },
  computed:{
    sample(){ return "sampledata" }
  }
};
```

My package.json:

```
"vue": "^2.6.11",
"v-runtime-template": "^1.10.0"
```

Problem : I got this error on console:

> vue.esm.js?a026:628 [Vue warn]: Property or method "sample" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property..

I have read some github issues as like [this](https://github.com/alexjoverm/v-runtime-template/pull/32) told me similar problem.

Maybe someone can help me how to resolve this of my simple implementation of using this v-runtime-template library? Many thanks.

Comment: inside script tag put    import Vue from 'vuex'; Vue.use(VRuntimeTemplate );

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how this trick can solve my problem, but this really save my life.
[Original source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55164363/8729463)
by [H.Eden](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8416885/h-eden)
So, I solve my problem by creating new vue file as v-runtime-template pivot.

RuntimePivot:vue:

```
<template>
  <v-runtime-template :template="`<div>${template}</div>`"></v-runtime-template>
</template>

<script>
import VRuntimeTemplate from "v-runtime-template";
export default {
    props:['template','props','listener'],
    components:{
        VRuntimeTemplate
    },
    name:"RuntimePivot",
    data(){
        return {
            myname:'everything'
        }
    },
    
}
</script>
```

Then I import the runtimePivot.vue template to my Page.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <RuntimePivot :template="template" :props="properties" /> 
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import RuntimePivot from "./RuntimePivot";
export default {
    components:{
        RuntimePivot 
    },
    name:"Page",
    data(){
        return {
            template:`<span>{{key}}</span>`,
            properties:{key:"value"}    
        }
    },
    
}
</script>
```

Better solution is still opened to you guys.